# Using Google Places Api for Webservices or Google Places API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-places-api

Im looking to use `Places AutoComplete` in my iOS applications but I am unsure of wether the `Google Places API for iOS` has matured enough? Im working on an application for work so I need to use a sound solution.

I've also noticed in their examples that the platform targets `iOS8.1` which I think is relatively high as I need to support `iOS7.1` (I know, I know). Regardless of supporting `iOS7` or not, should it not be `iOS8.0` not `iOS8.1`? The platform target is not stated anywhere else so I may be mistaken by believing that it doesnt support `iOS7`.

Also, `Google Places for iOS` is only available via `CocoaPods`.

There also seems to be a lot of crashes in their change logs.

So currently, the `Google Places API` for iOS doesnt seem suitable for my current project. Is it possible to continue to use the `Google Places API for WebServices`?

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/releases

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend the Google Places API for iOS.  It will be easier to use, and it will be easier to take advantage of future improvements in the Places API.

The Google Places API for iOS works with iOS 7.0 and up.  It's not stated very clearly in the docs, but if you dig around it's there.   https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start says:

> The Google Places API for iOS is packaged with the Google Maps SDK for
>   iOS.

And as the Google Maps SDK for iOS docs at https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start say:

> With the Google Maps SDK for iOS, you can build apps that target
>   native 32-bit or 64-bit devices running iOS 7.0 and later.

As far as crashes go: I think you're unlikely to encounter any (keep in mind the Places API for iOS has been available for over 6 months now, lots of time for bugs to emerge and be fixed), but if you do please [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Bug) at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/ — we're keen to fix any issues you have.

All that said, either solution should work pretty well for you!

Comment: Thanks for this. Will Google Places for iOS be released outside of CocoaPods?

Comment: Currently it's only distributed via CocoaPods.  Would you mind filing a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request)?  We'd love to know how you'd prefer us to distribute the SDK, and why :)